# Entity Framework Core Include with Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to bring a list of objects that have a list of child objects as well from the database.

Here is an example

```
 public class User 
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
 }

 public class Child 
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
 }
```

The problem here is that I cannot find a way to bring a list of Users and filter the Childs with a condition as well at the same time.

I tried something like this:

```
users = _context.Users.Where(e => e.Childs.Any(ec => ec.Id > 1))
```

But using this example if the condition is not met it will not bring the User back and I want all the users even if they do not have Childs or the condition is not met.

Also found this project: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus but  looks like it does not support EF Core for what I want to do.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Filtered include - unsupported in all EF versions including Core. Continually asked question on SO.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your comment but that does not answer my question. Do you know any alternative ?

Comment: Only with some explicit loading/navigation property fix-up relating tricks, similar to *You can also filter which related entities are loaded into memory.* example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). But it requires query to be materialized.

Comment: Finally, ef core 5 implemented filtering in Include. MSDN doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#filtered-include

Answer (score 10):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Our Library doesn't support Query Filter yet for .NET Core due to the N+1 queries issue.

Under our hood for EF6, our library was only doing a simple projection.

Something similar to this using your information:

```
var users = _Context.Users.Select(x => new {
                Users = x,
                Childs = x.Childs.Any(ec => ec.Id > 1)
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x.Users)
            .ToList();
```

However, for EF Core, the same projection makes a database roundtrip to get a child for every user (N+1 queries)

You can try the following projection and see if you get the same error.

I believe until the EF Core team fixes it, to my knowledge, there is not way to filter child entities.

```
SELECT [x].[Id], [x].[ColumnInt]
FROM [Lefts] AS [x]
go
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Rights] AS [ec1]
        WHERE ([ec1].[Id] > 1) AND (@_outer_Id1 = [ec1].[LeftId]))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END',N'@_outer_Id1 int',@_outer_Id1=1
go
exec sp_reset_connection
go
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Rights] AS [ec1]
        WHERE ([ec1].[Id] > 1) AND (@_outer_Id1 = [ec1].[LeftId]))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END',N'@_outer_Id1 int',@_outer_Id1=2
go
exec sp_reset_connection
go
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Rights] AS [ec1]
        WHERE ([ec1].[Id] > 1) AND (@_outer_Id1 = [ec1].[LeftId]))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END',N'@_outer_Id1 int',@_outer_Id1=3
go
exec sp_reset_connection
go
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Rights] AS [ec1]
        WHERE ([ec1].[Id] > 1) AND (@_outer_Id1 = [ec1].[LeftId]))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END',N'@_outer_Id1 int',@_outer_Id1=4
go
exec sp_reset_connection
go
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Rights] AS [ec1]
        WHERE ([ec1].[Id] > 1) AND (@_outer_Id1 = [ec1].[LeftId]))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END',N'@_outer_Id1 int',@_outer_Id1=5
go
```

**ANSWER Sub-Question:**

> With the new release of .NET core 2.0 does this problem got fixed ?

Unfortunately, Entity Framework is still not able to handle cast correctly with the V2.x

By example, this LINQ that use the Cast method doesn't work:

```
var ids = ctx.MyTables
    .Cast<IMyTable>()
    .Cast<MyTable>()
    .Where(x => x.SomeKey.Equals(keyId))
    .Select(x => x.MyFieldIntegerIWant)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT:** Status Update #1

Unfortunately, the EF Core team has still not fixed the N+1 queries issue with projection.

Looking at the latest status for the v3.0, I do not believe they plan to fix this kind of issue soon either: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10001#issuecomment-456581915

**EDIT:** Status Update #2

The `IncludeFilter` feature is now supported in the latest version of EF Plus (EF Core 2.x and EFCore 3.x)

Comment: With the new release of .NET core 2.0 does this problem got fixed ?

Comment: See the comment I added, in short, no... 2.0 still have the same issue

Comment: when/if they fix the issue, _**please**_ come back and update this answer!

Comment: This would be amazing for overly complex relational databases and working with EF in general as objects.

Comment: this is fixed now! are there any updates @JonathanMagnan ?

Comment: Yes @cyptus, our library already support it since a few weeks ago.